# Swift - Get Image creationDate and Location

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimage, phasset

A function in my app returns an image and I'm now trying to get the images `creationDate` and `location`.

How is this possible with/without using [PHAsset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phasset#1656308)?

Answer (score 3):

According to Apple's documentation, you should be able to do that using:

```
let location = asset.location
let creationDate = asset.creationDate
```

They are properties of [PHAsset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phasset) class.

Take a look at: [location](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phasset/1624788-location) and [creationDate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phasset/1624776-creationdate).

Comment: Yes I know that but I don't know how to get them for a particular uiimage. Can you turn a uiimage into a phasset?

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't know if this is possible.

Comment: @MoAbdul-Hameed did you find a way to get the location of an UIImage?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and it will return the `phAsset` in the info dictionary. Once you get the dictionary all the properties of `phAsset` will be available.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
       let asset = info[.phAsset] as? PHAsset
       print(asset?.creationDate ?? "None")
       print(asset?.location ?? "None")
       dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
    }
```